# Limit many to many relationship by number in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Three tables: users, roles and a pivot table (many to many) role_user.

```
user:
- id
- name

role:
- id
- name

role_user
- id 
- user_id: foreign key link to user
- role_id: foreign key link to role
```

If I wanted to limit the amounts of maximum roles a user can have to only 1 for example, I could put the role_id foreign link on the user as a role_1 field  instead of using a pivot table of many to many.

```
users:
- id
- name
- role_id_1
```

The same goes if I wanted only two roles per user.

```
users:
- id
- name
- role_id_1
- role_id_2
```

What if I wanted to limit the amount to 1, 2 or something else using a pivot table (Not using foreign role links on the user table) ? Is there an option for that in sql ?

Something like a composite unique index option including role_id and user_id in the pivot table, but instead of a constraint on the uniqueness, a custom constraint on the limit of the user_id number of appearances.

Comment: This is usually done using a Trigger (as most DBMSes don't support the necessary complex CHECK constraint). Btw, adding two role_ids to the users table would be a violation of 1st Normal Form, never ever do that. Additionally the `role_user` table (which is not called pivot-table, it's a junction or cross-reference table) doesn't need that useless `id` column, there's a Primary Key (user_id, role_id)

Comment: Thanks for the trigger reference.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way you can implement this in SQL without triggers.  It is a bit complicated, but you could do it.

It starts by adding another table.  Let me call it `RoleNumbers`.  This table would consist of one row for each possible role for a user.  So, you set it up with 1, 2, or however many roles you want.

Then for the junction table:

```
create table UserRoles (
    UserRoleId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    UserId int not null references users(user_id),
    RoleId int not null references roles(role_id),
    RoleNumber int not null references RoleNumbers(Number),
    unique (UserId, RoleId),
    unique (UserId, RoleNumber)
);
```

This uses my naming conventions.  I have no problem with having a synthetic key on a junction table.

When you insert a new record, you would have to assign a value to `RoleNumber` that is not already being used.  Hence, you get the limit.  The most efficient way to do this is via triggers, but that is not strictly necessary.  You could do an insert as:

```
insert into UserRoles(UserId, RoleId, RoleNumber)
    select $UserId, $RoleId, coalesce(max(RoleNumber), 0) + 1
    from UserRoles
    where UserId = $UserId;
```

`delete` would require a separate query for maintaining the numbering scheme.

Comment: That is an innovative approach. If I am understanding you correctly, the RoleNumber and UserId columns in the UserRoles should be unique together, and the RoleNumber table represent the abstract role posibilities for user. The amount of rows represent the maximum amount of roles wanted. Is that correct ?

Comment: Building on that, can I forgo the RoleNumber table and use an enum RoleNumber column in the UserRoles table which will be checked by a check constraint ex. "CHECK (RoleNumber < 2)" ?

Comment: `RoleNumber int not null distinct references RoleNumbers(Number),` I've never seen that `distinct` syntax, how does it work and which DBMS supports it? Of course you could also do `RoleNumber int not null check (RoleNumber between 1 and 2)`and add another `unique (UserId, RoleId,RoleNumber)`. But maintenance will be horrible anyway.

Comment: @dnoeth . . . That should have been `unique`.  As for the `check` constraint, it is a good idea, but MySQL doesn't actually do the check.

Comment: But `unique` is a constraint which does't allow multiple rows with the same value, so how is it supposed to work here? Or does mysql (again) not follow Standard SQL?

Comment: @dnoeth . . . That must be why I used the wrong syntax . . . the formulation was wrong ;)  I fixed it to have the unique constraint I actually intend.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, thanks. I see in the references that mysql does not support checks.